# Cypress: after clicking button page doesn't open

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, cypress, click

I need to click search button which should open a new page with search result. But click() function of does not work. Cypress clicks the button, but there is nothing happens, the current page just refreshes and the search result page does not open.

here is my HTML structure in the DOM:

```
<groupui-button type="submit" icon-only="" variant="tertiary" size="s" icon="search-24" title="Search" role="button" icon-position="left" target="self" class="hydrated"></groupui-button>
```

What I am really doing:

```
cy.get('groupui-button[icon="search-24"]').click({force:true})
```

I tried many ways, with `{force:true}` and without, and these also:
`.trigger('click')`, `.invoke('click')`, `.trigger('mouseover').click({force:true})`

It unfortunately does not work.

By the way other buttons work fine, only the search button has this issue, and I think this issue related to `type="submit"` of the **Vue.js** component. But manually everything works fine in any browser.
Here is the submitForm() itself:

```
<groupui-button
        type="submit"
        icon-only="true"
        variant="tertiary"
        size="s"
        icon="search-24"
        @click="submitForm()"
        :title="$t('dnc.search.title')"
      ></groupui-button>

submitForm() {
      if (this.hasInput) {
        this.actionUrl =
          this.searchUrl +
          this.advSearch +
          "?elpmSearchString=" +
          this.searchInput;
      } else {
        this.actionUrl = this.searchUrl + this.advSearch;
      }
    },
```

If you suggest plugin for Cypress like **cypress-real-events**, it is unfortunately does not support Firefox browser, so I cannot use that.

Can you provide any suggestion?

Comment: Since `type="submit"` causes a POST request, try `.trigger('submit')` after the click.

Comment: Also, try setting a `cy.intercept()` for the POST request and waiting for it. That way you will know the request has been fired and the search results have come back.

Comment: Lola, `.trigger('submit')` doesn't work before and after click ((. Can you please help me with `cy.intercept()`. I didn't get it.

Comment: It's a bit of a long shot - if you look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit), for plain HTML `<input type="submit">` fires a POST request. You can find out if your app does same by checking dev-tools/Network tab (not in Cypress but just chrome browser).

Comment: I just noticed adding `cy.wait()` didn't help, so waiting for `intercept` probably won't help either. But at least you should compare network traffic between non-Cypress browser and during Cypress test. If there's a POST request that does not occur during the test, you need to figure out how to trigger it in the test.

Comment: Also, try `cypress-real-events` with chrome - if it works, you are one step further than previously. You can always make that particular test conditional on browser="chrome".

Comment: Lola, with `cypress-real-events` everything works fine, but the client requires exactly Edge and Firefox (( that's why I refused this plugin, so it does not support Firefox.

Comment: Regarding dev-tools, I didn't receive anything in Network tab related to "submit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing worked, so I contacted our developers and they finally found another solution for the Search form. Now it works fine in Cypress.
Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form isn't reloading or doing something right before you click the search button. I had a similar issue when I couldn't click a checkbox unless I waited a second or 2 for the form to load. I am using angular and haven't found a better way to wait for observables and the like using Cypress so I used a simple `cy.wait(1000)`.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Unfortunately it still the same. I added wait before and after  click, nothing.

Comment: Maybe you can find the actual <button> component within the <groupui-button> in the shadow DOM and click that?

Comment: Sora, I tried get even up to svg icon, nothing